# Width of bars according to associated group

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

We have a dataframe that contains various values of a broadcast medium.

```
+----+-------+--------+------+-------------+
|    |   MHz | Slot   |   dB |   dB_median |
|----+-------+--------+------+-------------|
|  0 |    10 | Slot1  |   20 |        20.5 |
|  1 |    20 | Slot1  |   21 |        20.5 |
|  2 |    30 | Slot2  |   19 |        19   |
|  3 |    40 | Slot3  |   18 |        18   |
|  4 |    50 | Slot4  |   21 |        19   |
|  5 |    60 | Slot4  |   17 |        19   |
|  6 |    70 | Slot4  |   20 |        19   |
|  7 |    80 | Slot5  |   22 |        22   |
|  8 |    90 | Slot6  |   19 |        19   |
|  9 |   100 | Slot6  |   19 |        19   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-------------+
```

- `MHz` refers to the frequency of the carrier
- `Slot` refers to the name of the service
- `dB` refers to the measured value per carrier
- `dB_median` refers to the median value per service

A service is modulated on 1 or more carriers or in other words: a `Slot` can have a length of 1 or more `MHz` values.

I'm now looking for a way to plot this spectrum like:

[image]

But I only get to the point where I can color the single bars according to the related `Slot`:

[image]

Happy for any idea or hint.

---

## MWE

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    "MHz":[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
    "Slot":["Slot1","Slot1","Slot2","Slot3","Slot4",
            "Slot4","Slot4","Slot5","Slot6","Slot6"],
    "dB":[20,21,19,18,21,17,20,22,19,19],
    "dB_median":[20.5,20.5,19,18,19,19,19,22,19,19]
})

plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
g = sns.barplot(
    data=df_test,
    x="MHz",
    y="dB_median",
    hue="Slot"
)
sns.move_legend(g, "lower center", ncol=6, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Seems like this could be a sequence of fill_between for each slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested from Trenton McKinney, I found a solution with `fill_between`.

I am posting this solution in the hope that it may help someone in the future:

```
df2plot = (
    df_test
    .groupby("Slot")
    .agg({"MHz": [("min_mhz", lambda x: x.min() - 4), 
                  ("max_mhz", lambda x: x.max() + 4)],
          "dB_median": [("dB_median", "max")]}
    )
    .droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
    .reset_index()
)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
for index, row in df2plot.iterrows():
    plt.fill_between(
        x=[row.min_mhz,row.max_mhz], 
        y1=row.dB_median, 
        y2=0, 
        label=f"{row.Slot}"
    )
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Update: added `plt.ylim(ymin=0)`, thanks to JohanC.

[image]